# How to move values in a list

Tags: python, list, tuples

I'm still learning python, and am trying to move values in a list with loop. But dont know how to do it.

The example lists I've got (6 and 8 values):

```
lst1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[],[]]
lst2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[],[]]
```

I'd like to move the '1' to lst1[1][0], which would make it:

```
lst1 = [[2,3,4,5,6],[1],[]]
```

But I don't know how to do it with the commands. I would preferably have it in a function so I could use it with more variables such as a list with 9, 10, 11, etc... numbers in it.

Comment: **Hint:** 1. you have to extract first element from the leftmost list; 2. you have to add the element to the middle list; 3. you have to remove the first element from the leftmost list

Comment: Note that removing non-final items from a list is slow because all the subsequent items need to be moved, so it's best avoided, when practical.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do it:

```
In [11]: lst1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[],[]]

In [12]: lst1[1].append(lst1[0].pop(0))

In [13]: lst1
Out[13]: [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1], []]
```

Here, `lst1[0].pop(0)` "pops" the zeroth element of `lst1[0]` and appends it to `lst1[1]`.

Turning this into a function is left as an exercise for the reader. :-)

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you turn it into a function:

```
#this makes the function
def move_the_numbers():
    lst1 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6],[],[]]
    lst2 = [[1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8],[],[]]


    #this moves the number and appends it to the correct space in the list
    lst1[1].append(lst1[0].pop(0))


    print lst1


#this calls the function
move_the_numbers()
```

Comment: I think a function should accept `lst1` (or `lst2`) as an argument, they should not be hardcoded inside the function